# HashMap or List in Kotlin when size is only 20?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a dataset that contains only 20 piece of data, I will search them for 2 or 3 times, as

```
data class Person{
   val fullName: String,
   val someField: SomeClass
}
```

I know there are some concerns of HashMap just as memory and performance, 
and using HashMap will save several lines of code for me.  I'm not sure which is best for me, List or HashMap?

Comment: for 20 records, I don't think there will be any performance issue.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I don't want to be challenged: why not use HashMap(or LinkedMap)? or why use a high weight structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you need a structure from which you will be retrieving items randomly - use a HashMap
- When you will be retrieving items in order (e.g. using a for loop) - use an List

Scalability: 
LinkedHashMap is the most memory-hungry collection in JDK. It extends HashMap by using LinkedHashMap.Entry as an entry in the internal array of entries. LinkedHashMap.Entry extends HashMap.Entry by adding ‘before’ and ‘after’ pointers, thus implementing a linked dequeue. For us it means that LinkedHashMap.Entry consumes 40 bytes (8 bytes more than HashMap.Entry).

It means that LinkedHashMap consumes 40 * SIZE + 4 * CAPACITY bytes.

Comment: it's not that easy unfortunately.. and what about `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: The LinkedHashMap offers fast access to arbitrary elements as well as predictable ordering.

Comment: exactly.. my point was: choosing between a list or a map requires more considerations than simple item retrieval

Comment: It's no reason LinkedHashMap is fast. @SharanSalian

Comment: @BollMose Check the edit, There is always a trade off. Anyways use-case dependent. Always go for scalability.